# Как определить, куда установлена Java в CentOS 6.5?

Tags: java, linux

Как определить, куда установлена *Java* в *CentOS 6.5*.
Нужно знать, чтобы прописать пути к:

```
export JAVA_HOME= 
export PATH=
export CLASSPATH=
export PATH=
```

Comment: 1) наберите в консоли `alternatives --list`. Вывод поможет понять.
2) find / -name "javac"

Comment: А как Java можно обновить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто java в терминале выполняется?

`which java` выдаст полный путь до исполняемого файла. Скорее всего это симлинк потому

```
ls -la _путь_полученный_выше__
```

а там уже будет ясно. Скорее всего на уровень выше просто подняться по пути.

Answer (score 1):

Если программа `java` установлена из дистрибутивного пакета — то переопределять эти переменные для её функционирования не требуется.

Если же установлена каким-то иным методом — уточняйте необходимую информацию в инструкции по установке.

Answer (score 0):

`ls -alFh /etc/alternatives | grep bin/java`

Comment: Постарайтесь не ограничиваться в ответе, добавьте пояснения. PS: Это не является решением вопроса, так как при установке Oracle Java из тарболла по указанному пути ничего не будет. Проверено на боевом сервере!